# query does not work on php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query that I'm trying to make but I cant get it to work, any advise?

```
function getPrelaciones($carnet){

$result = ("SELECT mhm.Materia_codigo1 FROM Materia_has_Materia mhm, Materia m, (SELECT mha.Materia_codigo as materianovista FROM Materia_has_Alumno mha WHERE mha.Alumno_carnet = '%s')as n WHERE n.materianovista = mhm.Materia_codigo AND mhm.Materia_codigo1 != ' ' AND n.materianovista = m.codigo", $carnet);
print json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: What does `can't work` means?

Comment: im trying to make it work from php, it worked on sql workbench

Comment: You're not actually executing any database query, just creating a string.

Comment: yes, that is what i want, because i am sending it to a iOS application

Comment: @DCoder lol didn't notice that.

Comment: the error is expected content type {...}

Answer (score 1):

You haven't executed the query. Change this to,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT mhm.Materia_codigo1 FROM Materia_has_Materia mhm, Materia m, (SELECT mha.Materia_codigo as materianovista FROM Materia_has_Alumno mha WHERE mha.Alumno_carnet = '%s')as n WHERE n.materianovista = mhm.Materia_codigo AND mhm.Materia_codigo1 != ' ' AND n.materianovista = m.codigo", $carnet);
```

This is only useful, if you are using mysql. If no, you have to execute the query according to  the driver.

Note : I would suggest don't use mysql functions if you are using right now. Move to **mysqli** or **PDO**.

Comment: Soon to be removed: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: i missed "query", thanks

Answer (score 0):

you called the query wrong.

php needs to know where the query is for.

example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");
```

read more about mysql queries here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

try this and is $carnet connection string variable?

```
function getPrelaciones($carnet){

$result = mysql_query("SELECT mhm.Materia_codigo1 FROM Materia_has_Materia mhm, Materia m, (SELECT mha.Materia_codigo as materianovista FROM Materia_has_Alumno mha WHERE mha.Alumno_carnet = '%s')as n WHERE n.materianovista = mhm.Materia_codigo AND mhm.Materia_codigo1 != ' ' AND n.materianovista = m.codigo", $carnet);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print json_encode($rows);
}
```